# How to set the background colour of a Popup menu?

Tags: android, android-menu

Hey everyone I am dealing with a small problem with Popup menu. Honestly I dont know where is the problem, I tried to search the internet if I can find any answers but unfortunatelly I cant. So..

I created a custom toolbar and set the activity to no actionbar. Then I created a popUp menu in this toolbar. First I tried to change the icon of a menu via styles and it worked. But then I wanted to change the background and text color of a menu items.

This is the code I have in my design tab of the menu item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/fitItem1"
    android:title="Item 1"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/fitItem2"
    android:title="Item 2"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item android:id="@+id/fitItem3"
    android:title="Item 3"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

And even in the design menu it looked like this:
But when you start the app it looks by default (white background, black text)

[image: Menu items example]

So I thought that is it set somewhere in styles but there is nothing like that and every guide I tried to follow had no effect. Except style name="MyPopBackground" which actully changes the background.

```
   <resources>

        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@style/MyPopBackground</item>


    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/triple_dot_icon</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorLightGrey</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyPopBackground" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorGrey</item>
    </style>

    </resources>
```

There might be some useless styles but since I didnt know where is the prob. I left them there. My goal is to make that menu look like that one the image showed before.

I would be glad for any help, thanks for help.

Comment: Look at this , it’s the same situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381524/what-android-theme-can-i-use-to-change-the-toolbar-options-menu-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add popupMenu style to your AppTheme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

then at mainifest.xml

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

In style AppTheme, You add `<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorMenu</item>`